# Blindness to one's own good traits?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine a wonderful person, who does the nicest things for other people and is almost completely selfless, but that person is insecure and only focuses on their faults. They conveniently always forget all the good things they constantly do, and only seem to think about their flaws. They are either completely oblivious to their good traits or don't count them as high as their faults.

Is there a word for this kind of person?

Comment: There are those who would say that this is an inverted egotism, and that focusing on oneself in any way is incompatible with true selflessness.

Comment: Imposter syndrome fits the description, however I dont think there is one correct answer for this question because it would likely depend on **why** the person in question is not seeing his/her positive attributes, is it humility to the extreme or incapability of looking one's self objectively? Is it just insecurity or somehow lacking in comparison to others (i.e. a role model). In any case I think one could say that the person has low self esteem.

Comment: @posdef I wanted the question to be more about the individual's insecurity and inability to look at themselves objectively, rather than them being humble, so I think imposter syndrome fits very well.

Comment: 'Honest' might be suitable. They honestly assess what only they know of themselves regardless of what the public _think_ they know of them.

Comment: @NigelJ People like that tend to be very overcritical of themselves though, downplaying even very obvious achievements, so I don't think "honest" is a good fit for that.

Comment: @noClue As well as 'honest' I would add 'realistic'.

Comment: Depending upon precise requirement of meaning, **self-deprecating** could apply: modest about or critical of oneself.

Comment: I wrote up an answer "sell oneself short" but deleted, as it sounds like you want more.  If however, you wanted to say more that they "should be more confident than they are" without risking as much implying that they have general self-doubt you might consider it as an option .  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sell_oneself_short

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Imposter syndrome* would be one possible response:

> Impostor syndrome (also known as impostor phenomenon, fraud syndrome
>   or the impostor experience) is a concept describing individuals who
>   are marked by an inability to internalize their accomplishments and
>   have a persistent fear of being exposed as a "fraud".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome

Comment: Just for the record, the opposite is the [Dunning-Kruger effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning–Kruger_effect).

Comment: @LinuxBlanket  Good one! Adding to that, surveys demonstrate that huge, disproportionate percentages of people think they are *above average* in intelligence, skill, knowledge, whatever.